grep a pattern 1, but not if pattern B is present 2 lines above
I have a file which contains the following
SeqNumber       = 7915
Message ID      = LC083
Category        = Audit
AgentID         = RACLOG
Severity        = Warning
Timestamp       = 2024-09-28 04:41:22
Message         = I have an issue

until now, I'm grepping for "Warning", and that works as expected.
Now, I'd like to ignore the warning when the Message ID is "LC083"
I know I can grep -B 3 Warning to display this message ID, but I don't know how to then ignore this match.
EDIT : I'm sorry, but again, I forgot some details in my question, though the answers until here are very useful.
There can be multiple blocks in the file, including some warnings with an other Message ID, that need to be reported (only the LC083 -for now- needs to be ignored).
Thank you Stackoverflower for your answers !

do you have to worry about multiple Warning lines in the input and if so could some have ID = LC083 and some with ID != LC083? also, what exactly do you want the output to show ... just the string Warning or the whole line (ie, Severity = Warning)?

will the Message ID line always come before the Severity line?

Using any awk:
$ awk '/^Message ID/{id=$NF} /Warning/ && (id != "LC083")' file
$


$ awk '/^Message ID/{id=$NF} /Warning/ && (id != "foo")' file
Severity        = Warning
$

Also consider storing the values for every tag (attribute name) in an array and then you can access whichever of the values you like just by their tags, e.g.:
awk -v tgt='LC083' '
    {
        tag = val = $0
        sub(/[[:space:]]*=.*/, "", tag)
        sub(/^[^=]*=[[:space:]]*/, "", val)
        f[tag] = val
    }
    
    (tag == "Severity") && (val == "Warning") && (f["Message ID"] != tgt) {
        print
    }
' file

Although more code to write, it's far more robust and flexible than just using regexps.

Assumptions:

if the file contains the string LC083 then we output nothing else ...
if the file contains the string Warning then we output Warning

Using a pair of grep calls to implement our assumptions:
grep -qo LC083 filename || grep -o Warning filename

Three test files:
$ head test.?.dat
==> test.1.dat <==
SeqNumber       = 7915
Message ID      = LC083
Category        = Audit
AgentID         = RACLOG
Severity        = Warning
Timestamp       = 2024-09-28 04:41:22
Message         = I have an issue

==> test.2.dat <==
SeqNumber       = 7915
Message ID      = XX000
Category        = Audit
AgentID         = RACLOG
Severity        = Warning
Timestamp       = 2024-09-28 04:41:22
Message         = I have an issue

==> test.3.dat <==
SeqNumber       = 7915
Message ID      = LC083
Category        = Audit
AgentID         = RACLOG
Severity        = Info
Timestamp       = 2024-09-28 04:41:22
Message         = just a heads up

Running our dual grep solution against the three test files:
for fname in test.?.dat
do
    echo "####### ${fname}"
    grep -qo LC083 "${fname}" || grep -o Warning "${fname}"
done

This generates:
####### test.1.dat
####### test.2.dat
Warning
####### test.3.dat


Implementing the same logic with an awk script:
awk '/LC083/ {exit} /Warning/ {print "Warning"}' filename

NOTE: this assumes the LC083 line comes before the Warning line
Running against the three test files:
for fname in test.?.dat
do
    echo "####### ${fname}"
    awk '/LC083/ {exit} /Warning/ {print "Warning"}' "${fname}"
done

This generates:
####### test.1.dat
####### test.2.dat
Warning
####### test.3.dat


Use this Perl one-liner:
perl -F'\s*=\s*' -lane '$val{ $F[0] } = $F[1]; next LINE unless $F[0] eq "Severity" and $F[1] eq "Warning"; print unless $val{"Message ID"} eq "LC083";' infile

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
-e : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
-n : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to $_ by default.
-l : Strip the input line separator ("\n" on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
-a : Split $_ into array @F on whitespace or on the regex specified in -F option.
-F'\s*=\s*' : Split into @F on = surrounded on both sides by 0 or more whitespace characters.
Field names and values are first stored in array @F as $F[0] and $F[1], correspondingly. Then they are stored in hash %val. All lines without Severity = Warning are skipped. The warning from Message ID = LC083 is also skipped. Otherwise, the warning is printed into STDOUT.
See also:

perldoc perlrun: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches


Use this one-liner that uses GNU grep (with -P option to use Perl regexex). It also uses paste to convert pairs of lines into single line. Two additional grep commands keep warnings and discard message ID LC083. Finally, cut keeps the second field (-f2), which is just the warning:
grep -P '(Message ID|Severity)' infile | paste - - | grep Warning | grep -v LC083 | cut -f2


Wouldn't you want the f1 Message ID?

Just because I like to offer alternatives, here's one in sed -
sed -En '
   /^Message ID += LC083 *$/d
   /^Message ID += /,/^Severity += /{
     /^Message ID += /h
     /^Severity += Warning *$/{
       x
       p
     }
   }' file

Or, with GNU semicolons, as a "one-liner" -
sed -En '/^Message ID += LC083 *$/d; /^Message ID += /,/^Severity += /{ /^Message ID += /h; /^Severity += Warning *$/{ x; p; }; }' file

This should spit out the Message ID lines with matching Severity of Warning so long as the Message ID is not LC083.
It has the advantage (like awk) of being a single process solution.
If you want the whole relevant block, I'd use awk in "paragraph mode". If there's a blank line between then that's really easy -
awk -v RS='' '/\nMessage ID += LC083 *\n/{next} /\nSeverity += Warning *\n/{print}' file

This works even if the order of records is inconsistent.
If there's no blank line, and/or if you just want the Message IDs, you could cheat a little and use Message ID as the record delimiter...
awk -v RS='\nMessage ID += ' '/^ *LC083 *\n/{next} /\nSeverity += Warning *\n/{print gensub(/ *\n.*/,"","1")}' file

(This one only prints the ID code, but that has the advantage or reducing redundant output.)
These are also single-process "one-liners".

If you wanted to print the entire matching block you can set the record separator to the first field, set the field separator to a newline and then match full lines like so:
awk 'BEGIN{
        RS="SeqNumber";
        FS="\n";
    }
    /\nSeverity *= Warning\n/ {
        if (!/\nMessage ID *= LC083\n/) {
            print RS $0
        }
    }' file

Note that with this method you have to print the record separator or the first block will be missing it.

Created array index related to SeqNumeber line (first line of serie for each data) and add line info into array.
Next, filter if MI[i]!~/ LC038$/ (Messenger ID) and print data.
#!/bin/bash
#$1=data.file
#
awk '{OFS="\n"}
/SeqNumber/{n=NR;Sn[NR]=$0}
/Message ID/{MI[NR-(NR-n)]=$0}
/Category/{C[NR-(NR-n)]=$0}
/AgentID/{A[NR-(NR-n)]=$0}
/Severity/{S[NR-(NR-n)]=$0}
/Timestamp/{T[NR-(NR-n)]=$0}
/Message/{M[NR-(NR-n)]=$0}
END{for(i in Sn)if(MI[i]!~/ LC083$/)
{print Sn[i],MI[i],C[i],A[i],S[i],T[i],M[i]}
}' $1


try this:
grep -A 1 "Warning" logfile.log | grep -v "LC083"

This will display all lines containing "Warning", but skip showing the line containing "LC083" and any following lines, effectively ignoring the "LC083" Message ID. The output will include the "Warning" line, but exclude the matching "LC083" line.

The message ID is several lines before severity, not on the next line.
